# How to set innerText in JavaScript for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, text, innertext

I am trying to set the innerText between an element's start and end tag in Chrome, but so far its not working. Why is that? I have tried these:

```
element.balanceText = "Changed.";
element.innerText = "Changed.";
element.innerHTML = "Changed.";
element.textContent = "Changed.";
element.value = "Changed.";
$(element).val("Changed.");
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/La1tadpd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsFiddle is configured to use Coffee Script not plain JavaScript, and because of this, you're getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: reserved word "var"

Due to the input tag being invalid HTML, I suggest removing the additional text node that the browser creates, then replace the input element with a div containing the text you want:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
element.nextSibling.parentNode.removeChild(element.nextSibling);

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'Changed.';

element.parentNode.replaceChild(div, element);
```

```html
<input id='test'>Hello</input>
```

Comment: Good catch, but...and you may find this weird, but for what I'm trying to do, I need to set "Changed." between the tags of the input element...so when I inspect the page, I want to see <input>Changed.</input> Right now, although element.value works, I still see "Hello." beside the element.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately the site's HTML is out of my control and I can only use JavaScript (I'm injecting JavaScript into the Outlook Web App's default.aspx for a customer). It uses MVC and this is how it presents this control, malformed and all. Is there a way to set text between two tags like this, beside the fact that its malformed?

Answer (score 1):

input is a void element u cannot do anything beyond

so we write `<input/>` not `<input></input>` because its cannot have custom content

checkout the tutorial here http://naveendev.hol.es/tutorial/void-elements-in-html

NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement': The 'input' element does not support text insertion.

because its a void element